# Error al mostrar las imágenes de storage cada que se actualizan

Tags: php, laravel, img, storage

Buen dia tengo un error al actualizar mi imagen en storage. Cuando subo la imagen por primera vez y se muestra en la vista todo pasa perfectamente funcionando al 100 pero cuando quiero actualizar la imagen y veo la vista nuevamente sigue la imagen antigua.

> **NOTA:** La imagen la visualizo cambiada al acceder al storage (no existe la vieja solo la del update), las rutas de la base de datos cambian de acuerdo a la extensión del archivo (muestro las imágenes con rutas en la base de datos).

Muestra de las imágenes:

```
@foreach($mostrar as $item)
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
    <div class="blog-item">
        <div class="img">
          <img style="height:200px;" src="{{$item->Imagen}}" alt="Blog image" class="img-fluid" />
        </div>
        <div class="body">
            <div class="meta">
                <a href="#" style="pointer-events: none; cursor: default;">
                    <i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>
                    <span>{{$item->created_at}}</span>
                </a>
                <a href="#" style="pointer-events: none; cursor: default;">
                    <i class="far fa-user"></i>
                    <span>Numeralia</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <h2>
                <a href="#">{{$item->Nombre_Encuesta}}</a>
            </h2>
            <p>
                {{$item->Descripcion}}
            </p>
            <a href="{{$item->PDF}}" title="Read More" target="_blank" class="blog-button">Descargar PDF <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Carga de las imágenes:

```
public function agregar_encuesta(Request $request){
    $extensionimg = $request->file('img')->extension();
    $extensionpdf = $request->file('pdf')->extension();
    storage::putFileAs('public/pdf/'.$request->Nombre_Encuesta,$request->file('pdf'),$request->Nombre_Encuesta.".".$extensionpdf);
    storage::putFileAs('public/img/'.$request->Nombre_Encuesta,$request->file('img'),$request->Nombre_Encuesta.".".$extensionimg);
    $nuevo=new encuesta;
    $nuevo->Nombre_Encuesta=$request->Nombre_Encuesta;
    $nuevo->Descripcion=$request->Descripcion;
    $nuevo->Imagen='storage/img/'.$request->Nombre_Encuesta."/".$request->Nombre_Encuesta.".".$extensionimg;
    $nuevo->PDF='storage/pdf/'.$request->Nombre_Encuesta."/".$request->Nombre_Encuesta.".".$extensionpdf;
    $nuevo->save();
    return back()->with('mensaje_Exito','Encuesta Agregada con exito');
}
```

Remplazo de las imágenes:

```
public function subida_imagen(Request $request){
    $extensionimg = $request->file('img')->extension();
    Storage::deleteDirectory('public/img/'.$request->Nombre_Encuesta);
    storage::putFileAs('public/img/'.$request->Nombre_Encuesta,$request->file('img'),$request->Nombre_Encuesta.".".$extensionimg);
    encuesta::where('Nombre_Encuesta','=',$request->Nombre_Encuesta)
    ->update(['Imagen' => 'storage/img/'.$request->Nombre_Encuesta."/".$request->Nombre_Encuesta.".".$extensionimg]);
    return redirect('/admin')->with('mensaje_cambio_imagen','Imagen Cambiada Satisfactoriamente');
    }
```

Comment: Por qué borras la encuesta antes de modificarla?

Comment: estoy borrando la carpeta donde se encuentran la imagen de la encuesta para volver a crearla con el id random de la imagen nueva